# What is the relation between parser combinators and recursive descent parsers?

Tags: parsing

What is the relation between parser combinators and recursive descent parsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia link on [parser combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinators) is actually pretty reasonable. From it one of the first things we learn is that "Parser combinators use a top-down parsing strategy", i.e. recursive descent.

Combinators themselves are building blocks for parsers, but they lean toward recursive descent.